# Suppose you pay 3.00 dollars to roll a fair die with the understanding that you will get back 5.00 dollars...

Tags: probability

I am really lost on these two question just wondering if someone could lend me a helping hand..

Suppose you pay 3.00 dollars to roll a fair die with the understanding that you will get back 5.00 dollars for rolling a 3 or a 6, nothing otherwise. What is your expected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value is the sum of the probablity of each outcome multiplied by the "value" of each outcome.

Its sort of like a special average.

In your case each outcome has probability $\frac{1}{6}$. and you get 5 dollars when you roll 3 or 6 when you roll something else.

So the expected value is

$\frac{0}{6}+\frac{0}{6}+\frac{5}{6}+\frac{0}{6}+\frac{0}{6}+\frac{5}{6}=\frac{10}{6}=\frac{5}{3}$.

This means loosely that if you played this game a lot you should expect to win on average  about 1.66 dollars, while you payed 3 to play it.  Clearly this is a great idea if you want to lose money.

Comment: Note that you should expect to win $\frac 5 3 = 1.66666...$ dollars while paying $3$ dollars to play it.  Otherwise you are correct.

Comment: right, edited, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you explain what you have tried.  We don't just answer homework questions here as it does not aid in understanding but we will walk you through it if you explain where you are stuck.

As a hint: The general way to look at problems like this is to multiply the expected net win (or loss) of each possible outcome by the probability of that outcome and summing the results.

Aka, if you roll a 1 (probability $\frac 1 6$) you win 0 dollars but spent 3 dollars so:

$$(0-3)*\frac 1 6$$ is the contribution of rolling a 1 to your solution.  Can you solve for the other numbers on the die? Can you simplify this by combining all winning rolls and all losing rolls?